# iOS 5, Can't set NC Widget UIView height

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, height

I am creating a [NC Widget](http://www.google.com/search?q=NC%20Widget) and can't seem to adjust the height of the widget.

Here is my code:

```
-(UIView *)view {
if (_view == nil)
{
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(2,0,316,191); // Added
    _view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:(frame)] autorelease]; //(2., 0., 316., 71.)]; <--ORIGINAL VALUE

    // Setting frame Height dont work... :/

    UIImage *bg = [[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"/System/Library/WeeAppPlugins/SMSWidget.bundle/Background.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:5 topCapHeight:71];
    UIImageView *bgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:bg];
    bgView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 316, 191);
    [_view addSubview:bgView];
    [bgView release];

}
```

Comment: where is this? if it is in UIViewController override loadView instead.

Comment: what exactly is happening? be moer specific about the problem. just posting a getter can be anything..

Comment: okey, i´m making a tweak for iPhone and i need to get the view to change the height size... How do i do that? Changing the value don`t work... :/

Comment: change _view to view.. and simply this code can mean anything what us -(UIView *)view {  // code } is for.. is it a function u r using or just to replresent code here.. please be more specific.

Comment: cant do that, bad result... But -(UIView *)view {//code} is for setting up the View.. ( UI ).

Comment: The code compiles, and works, but i cant change the Height of the view.... :/ I really cant figure out why.... o.O

Comment: figured it out.. I needed:
- (float)viewHeight
{
    return 71.0f;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example of how you can do that :

```
float myWidgetHeigth = 500 ; // The desired height
_view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(2, 0, 316, myWidgetHeigth)];

UIImage *bg = [[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:@"/System/Library/WeeAppPlugins/WorldClockNC.bundle/WeeAppBackground.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(5, 5, 5, 5)];
UIImageView bgview = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:bg];
bgview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 316, myWidgetHeigth);
[_view addSubview:bgview];
```

If you are developing a plugin for the notification Center, refer to the BBWeeAppController-Protocol.h you will need also to implement this method : "- (float)viewHeight".

Also, I have seen from your code you are using theses methods "stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:5 topCapHeight:71", that are deprecated in IOS 5.0 --> https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIImage/stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight: So, use the method "resizableImageWithCapInsets" ;-).

I'm not a pro on it, I'm learning ObjC, so if you have somes questions, let me know.